# How can I stop AWS lambda from recursive invocations

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that will read an excel file and do some stuffs and then store the result in a different S3 bucket.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    try:
        status = int(event['status'])

        if status:
            Reading_Bucket_Name = 'read-data-s3'
            Writing_Bucket_Name = 'write-excel-file-bucket'

        
            rowDataFile = 'Analyse.xlsx'
            HTMLfileName = 'index.html'

            url = loading_function(Reading_Bucket_Name=Reading_Bucket_Name, Writing_Bucket_Name=Writing_Bucket_Name, rowDataFile=rowDataFile, HTMLfileName=HTMLfileName)
            
            status = 0

            return {"statusCode": 200, "URL": url}

        else:
            return {"statusCode": 400, "Error": "The code could not be executed"}

    except Exception as e:
        print('#________ An error occurred while reading Status code int(event[status]) ________#')
        print(e)
        raise e
        return None
```

The code is only supposed to work once! And that it returns the URL and then turns off and exit the Lambda function.

**But the problem is**: I will get the first output, and then the lambda function will call itself again! And it will go to the exception and execute it at least many times! Because there is no event['status']. 'This must be received if I call this function by:

```
{
  "status": "1"
}
```

How can I stop execution after getting the first output?

**Update**:

**This will cause the problem** by uploading a new file to an S3 bucket:

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    fig.write_html('/tmp/' + HTMLfileName, auto_play=False)

    response = s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/' + HTMLfileName, Writing_Bucket_Name, HTMLfileName, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read', 'ContentType':'text/html'})
    return True
```

Comment: Why would the lambda called again? I don't get that.

Comment: @AnthonyB. I have no idea why; if I just open the logs, I will see multiple calls from the same function

Comment: how is your lambda triggered? Via S3 notification or something else. If you don't know how it is triggered, then how can we help you??

Comment: @AnthonyB. I triggered it with the Test button

Comment: and did you create an event with status key? something like this?
`{
  "status": "1"
}`

Comment: yes I did, "status": "1" and I was able to get this output   return {"statusCode": 200, "URL": url}

Comment: well then I don't see why the lambda would be called another time. Unless it has an external trigger.

Comment: It is possible that the Lambda function is creating an object an Amazon S3 bucket, and that bucket has been configured to trigger the Lambda function when an object is created. Does the problem still happen if you comment-out the `loading_function` line?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, The problem will not happen again! I can see that the problem occurs by writing something inside S3! I have updated my question

Comment: @Jonathan this seems like there is an S3 trigger to invoke the lambda function. Look at your s3 bucket where you save the file to. See if there is any trigger that invokes the Lambda function . You can look at EventBridge also

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Lambda function appears to be running when a new object is created in the Amazon S3 bucket, it would appear that **the bucket has been configured with an Event Notification** that is triggering the AWS Lambda function.

To check this, go the to bucket in the S3 management console, go to the **Properties** tab and scroll down to **Event notifications**. Look for any configured events that trigger a Lambda function.